# Send data to angularjs from nodejs for flash-message

Tags: angularjs, node.js, connect-flash

Like we send data from nodejs to ejs templete

`server.js`

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
});
```

`login.ejs`

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>
```

Is there a way using angularjs instead of ejs. I am using connect-flash for flash messages.